# Function which is already bind to the component still shows errors with Uncaught TypeError: _this4.handleDeleteItem is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-bootstrap-table

I have already bound the function in my component constructor but it still shows error with Uncaught TypeError: _this4.handleDeleteItem is not a function. I am using react bootstrap table2 column formatter for edit and delete buttons and I want to setState from there.

```
       return (
          <div className="text-center">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning mr-1">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faEdit }/>
              </button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.handleDeleteItem(row.id)}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={ faTrash }/>
              </button>
           </div>
            )
        }
```

```
     this.setState({
         showModal: true,
         delItem: item_id
     });
   }
```

Comment: Please show where you define `handleDeleteItem`.